# How to reduce size of strings.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-edittext

I have an android app which was 0.3MB in size before adding support for more languages. 
When i added support for 10 other languages using "values-es", "values-ar" etc.... the app size tripled.
This is understandable as my app uses alot of text. And i assume the app size was caused by the new folders and strings.xml files of each locale values folder.
Is there ant way to reduce the sizes of these files. I've removed unnecessary spacing and formatting that they are hardly visible. I have also been using proguard.

Comment: So it's now 0.9MB?  Why are you worried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can release separate apk files for each of your locales, you can mark them in the developer console i think to be just for specific languages. each apk would have just a single language.

But this is not something i would recommend. 0.9 megabytes is nothing today on the market. don't worry about it and just build it as a single apk. It is much easier to manage the updates and everything developer-wise if its just a single apk.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to reduce the size of strings.xml is to remove unused strings. you can find unused strings easily by using [Android LINT](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint)